# Why does Jupyter notebook on Mac show blank page?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Google Chrome is showing a blank page when I open a .ipyb file with jupyter notebook. I have already removed and reinstalled Anaconda (v2.1.2). How to deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: You probably have error stacktrace in your terminal/console. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, where can I find the error stacktrace? There is no error message or so popping up so I don't even know it is an error:( @AlexanderB.

Comment: how do you start your jupyter? I would guess it's a command line. So look there and verify that everything is ok. Btw if you can't find anything - switch browser for this time. Sometimes there might be some glitches.

Comment: I just started the jupyter notebook on Safari and it worked LOL! Thanks a lot! I was using Google Chrome but it still showed a blank page when i tried to open a .ipynb file.

Answer (score 3):

I also have the same problem with Mac. Downgrade to the 5.7.5 version solves it for me:

```
pip uninstall notebook
pip install notebook==5.7.5
```